# Generated column based on data from another table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two tables, `Faculty` and `FacultyEmail` who have a 1:1 relationship, with the following attributes:

```
+-------------+     +--------------+
|   Faculty   |     | FacultyEmail |
+-------------+     +--------------+
|  FacultyID  |     |  FacultyID   |
|  FirstName  |     |  Email       |
|  LastName   |     +--------------+
+-------------+
```

I need to auto generate the `Email` column based on the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields in `Faculty` such as: `firstname.lastname@gmail.com`

My question is whether this is possible? And if so, how would I go about writing up the DDL for this?

This is the DDL I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Faculty`
(
    `FacultyID` INT NOT NULL,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`FacultyID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FacultyEmail`
(
    `FacultyID` INT NOT NULL,
    `Email` VARCHAR(90) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (...), -- What goes here?
    PRIMARY KEY (`FacultyID`)
    FOREIGN KEY (`FacultyID`)
        REFERENCES `Faculty` (`FacultyID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that a generated column can handle what you want, since it would require a formal query to obtain the first and last names.

Comment: What would be a better alternative @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: Should I just create the field and allow someone to just insert data later?

Comment: If a given faculty member can only have a single first and last name, then maybe the email data belongs in the `Faculty` table.  That is, maybe get rid of the `FacultyEmail` table.

Comment: Generated column may refer to current row values only, except autoincremented column. It cannot refer to another rows or another tables.

Comment: Oh I see @Akina

Comment: You may use regular stored column and BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE triggers.

Comment: From the other side - the value which you need may be easily created in retrieving query and does not need to be stored at all.

Comment: The triggers / redacting the table entirely are good ideas. Unfortunately since it's a data specification to make the faculty have that specific email and table, I can't use a retrieving query and I'm unable to remove the table entirely. I could implement the trigger however

Comment: What if two members of faculty share the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say I have two tables, Faculty and FacultyEmail who have a 1:1 relationship, with the following attributes:

If it's truly a 1:1 relationship, a second table is an unnecessary complication. With a single table a generated column can be used.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Faculty`
(
    FacultyID int not null primary key auto_increment,
    FirstName varchar(255) not null,
    LastName varchar(255) not null,
    Email varchar(255) as
      (lower(concat(firstname,'.',lastname,'@wossamotta.edu'))) stored not null,
    unique(Email)
);
```

However, a generated column cannot be updated. Your Faculty may not appreciate being unable to pick their email address. Consider using `default` instead.

```
    Email varchar(255) not null  
      default(lower(concat(firstname,'.',lastname,'@wossamotta.edu'))),
```

> Unfortunately since it's a data specification to make the faculty have that specific email and table

If you must have a FacultyEmail "table" for compatibility, consider a view.

```
create view FacultyEmail
  as select FacultyID, Email from Faculty
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e0227da41bc0678141dfc31e6a998a1).

---

If you really want two tables, you can write an `after insert` trigger.

```
create trigger default_faculty_email
  after insert 
  on Faculty for each row
  insert into FacultyEmail (facultyid, email)
    values(
      NEW.facultyid,
      lower(CONCAT(NEW.firstname,'.',NEW.lastname,'@wossamotta.edu'))
    );
```

However, after that there's nothing preventing a FacultyEmail from being deleted leaving a Faculty with no FacultyEmail. So wee need another trigger to prevent that.

```
create trigger ProtectFacultyEmail
  before delete
  on FacultyEmail for each row
  signal sqlstate '45000'
    set message text = 'FacultyEmail cannot be directly deleted. Delete the Faculty row instead.';
```

This prevents directly deleting from FacultyEmail, but allows the `on delete cascade`.

As you can see, a second table raises a lot of complications.

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d1834958e5f09c708dbe96a0e9bd809).

---

## Notes

- I don't believe there is a need for an `on update cascade`, there's nothing in FacultyEmail to update. If the FacultyID can change that's a poor primary key. Consider an independent ID column separate from any mutable ID.
- `varchar(45)` does not save any space, it only sets a maximum size. Maximum size is a business rule and should not be hard-coded into the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make use of another table or subquery in the expr part of generated column syntax.

Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html